# How to add reply comment feature in custom comment form

Tags: wordpress, comments

I have created a custom comment template; Here created a form and stored the data in my custom table. The stored data showing from table in frontend.
This comment form is calling with in a loop for some post. Now i want to add reply feature on it, but i am confusing how to add this feature. please suggest me any body..

Comment: you need to create custom table like 'wp_comment_reply' with `comment_id` and store the replies

Comment: @vel thank you for your suggestion. I have created a custom table for storing comments of my childpost, so is it possible to use my table to store replies too. Please see my table 'subpostcomments' columns :

 comment_id , post_id , subpost_id , comment_author , author_email , comment_content , comment_date , PRIMARY KEY (comment_id)

Comment: Sub Post is custom post type?

Comment: No, actually its a list items which is created under a parent post. for this i have used  the plugin "Top Ten lists" and now i am modifying this.

Comment: @vel check this plugin https://wordpress.org/plugins/top-ten-lists/

Comment: Yes. you can store sub post id also

Comment: Yes, i have already done this. But for reply and nested reply how to do it

Comment: create another field like `level`

Comment: @vel, can you please elaborate your answer. I ma not getting exactly what are you talking.

Comment: main post level is 1, nested post level is increase by 1